# bash script for kill and re-run processes: not working properly

Tags: linux, bash, cron, kill, kill-process

I've crontab set like this

```
*/3 * * * * /usr/local/bin/checkHomeAssistant >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

where the checkHomeAssistant script check if the "shopList" process is on, otherwise I would like to close every process of chromium that are going and start the homeAssistant script.
here is the code

```
#!/bin/bash

#lo script che esegue nell’ambiente crontab (non X) deve sapere in che ambiente grafico deve agire e con quali variabili d’ambiente
export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority

checkShopList=$(ps –ef | grep –v grep | grep –c shopList)
checkChromium=$(ps –ef | grep –v grep | grep –c chromium-browser)

if [ $checkShopList –eq 0 ]; then
 if [ $checkChromium –eq 1 ]; then
 pkill chromium
 sleep 5
 fi
 /home/pi/Desktop/homeAssistant
fi
```

where the homeAssistant script is

```
    #!/bin/bash

sleep 5

/home/pi/Documents/QTProjects/shopList/build/ShopList &
chromium-browser --app=http://www.dakboard.com --start-maximized &
chromium-browser http://www.google.com --start-maximized &
#xvkbd -geometry 700x300 -compact minimizable $

sleep 5

wmctrl -r "DAKboard" -t 0
wmctrl -r "MainWindow" -t 1
wmctrl -r "Google - Chromium" -t 2

wmctrl -s 0
```

my problem is that the checkHomeAssistant script messes up with the Killing of the chromium istances: not always all the istances are killed and sometimes it kills them later...
suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't this `[ $checkChromium –eq 1 ]` be greater than or equal to? Also, does `pgrep` not work for `checkShopList`? And instead of checking if chromium is running, why not `pkill` and then check the return status which tells you if you need to sleep. You could also move the killing of chromium to the start of the `homeAssistant` script since it presumably always needs to happen. Then your cron job becomes something like `pgrep shopList || homeAssistant`.

Comment: yes you're right, it should be Greater than 1. 

but I have some questions: what does `pgrep` do? and what does `pgrep shopList || homeAssistant` do?

Comment: From the man page: "pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout." The `pgrep pattern || homeAssistant` says if pgrep doesn't return success, then run homeAssistant.